# Access data from another element in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to get the data "course_name" from a component view.

[image]

I have a component . This component comes from element-ui.
In my  component, I have an `event` object that contains the`course_name` data.

[image]

I would like to use the name of the event to use it as a title. I can not access it. I tried by doing in my file "header.blade.php":

```
<el-header>
  @{{ event.course_name }}
</el-header>
```

but I get an error :

`Property or method "event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

How to access the title of the event?

Thank you very much

Comment: do you want access the event title from your `ELHeader`, right? Could you show us your `ELHeader` data? Is this `event title` changed inside the `Event` element?

Comment: @RaphaelParreira I do not have access to the `Elheader` element because it's a component that comes from element-ui. I edit my code to show how I call it.

Comment: Ok... So, we need to know the `ELHeader` parent element data. You can post a print, like you did for `Event`.

Comment: what is the `element ui` component to see their document

Comment: Are you using `vuex`?

Comment: I highly recommend using vuex in this case